# ¿Como puedo comprobar si ha vuelto a hacer click de nuevo?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo un programa para `Android` con acceso a base de datos. Entonces tengo un botón editar, el cual cuando le pulso desactivo un botón crear. Para modificar un texto.

Entonces quiero que cuando vuelva a pulsar al botón editar (que en este momento tiene de texto en el botón, "Guardar"). Pues haga una serie de cosas, mi problema es que no sé que tengo que poner de condición en el if para saber si ha pulsado el botón cuando su valor es Guardar.

Copio lo relacionado al botón editar, el if cómo se puede ver lo tengo vacío. Haber si alguien puede echarme una mano en lo que tengo que poner en la condición. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
private Button btnEditar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnEditar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);

btnEditar.setOnClickListener(this);

}


public void onClick(View v) {
 switch (v.getId()) {

  case R.id.btnEditar:
   // Si hay alguna receta seleccionada permitimos su modificación
  if(c!=null){
   editReceta.setText(txtReceta.getText());
   btnCrear.setEnabled(false);
   btnEditar.setText("Guardar");

  if(...){                    db.actualizar(c.getId(),editNombre.getText().toString(),editReceta.getText().toString());
        btnCrear.setEnabled(true);
        btnEditar.setText("Editar");
     }  
   }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define una variable en la clase:

```
private int haGuardadoDosOcasiones = 0;
```

cuando realice el guardado incrementa la variable, cuando se realice en dos ocasiones el valor de `haGuardado` seria 2 :

```
haGuardado++;
```

Ahora en tu if puedes definir que realice la actualización si ha "guardado" en dos ocasiones, puedes también reiniciar la variable al realizar lo indicado en el bloque del código:

```
 if(haGuardado > 1){                    
 db.actualizar(c.getId(),editNombre.getText().toString(),editReceta.getText().toString());
        btnCrear.setEnabled(true);
        btnEditar.setText("Editar");

       //reinicia variable
       haGuardado = 0;
}
```